# Scale won't save

Tags: scale

What could be the reason that Blender won't save a model's scale. Every time I scale and save a particular model, then re-open it, it jumps back to it's original scale. Feel like I might have accidentally enabled something that I shouldn't have.

Comment: Do you have much experience in setting a keyframe?  Do you recall setting a keyframe?

Comment: Please include a screen snapshot so we can see your keyframes and scale values and constraints .

Comment: sorry for necro-ing but I have to same problem and do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have set keyframes then keyframes will supersede a temporary scale action.  Test the results  when you scale and set a keyframe.

You can test by moving the frame position back and forth and verifying your intentions have been recorded.

If you have any keyframes then a scale operation may just a temporary exploration.  Keyframes have CRUD abilities... for the operations of Create Read Update and Delete.

https://youtu.be/8Wb_ftxZ37o

Comment: You're right! I accidentally set a keyframe. Didn't even think about that. Thanks!

Comment: Blender has a lot of things to remember.  This little problem happens all the time.  If you feel this candidate answer has answered your question you may mark it as the answer ... or you can downvote as well.  Thanks.